# When EXACTLY is the cut off for upgrading to SagePay v3.0?

Tags: opayo

I am aware that 31st July has been noticed as the cut off but do them actually mean by midnight tonight?

Answer (score 0):

We require all FORM vendors who are using an older protocol to upgrade to v3.00 by 31 July 2015 otherwise there is a risk you will not be able to process transactions.

How to upgrade: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-integration-document/migrate-to-v3

Please note, our MySagePay Virtual terminal is not effected for FORM users as v3.00 protocol is used through this method.

To find out what options are available to you, email upgrade@sagepay.com, for an immediate response.

Regards

Sage Pay Support
0845 111 4455